# Expand a list of files including globs, which are defined in a file

Tags: bash, wildcards, shopt

I'm using bash. Suppose I have a file named `filelist`, which contains a list of files:

```
stuff/**/*.csv     # to keep it simple (without loops), assume just one entry
#*.txt
#foo.md
#bar.bin
```

And I want to expand that:

```bash
ls $(cat filelist)
```

I get:

> ls: cannot access 'stuff/**/*.csv': No such file or directory

What I want is to expand that into a list of files which I can pipe to my main app for processing. How can I do that?

Comment: The last command work fine for me. What is the result of `set -o|grep glob`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov `noglob   off`

Comment: @ilkkachu bash (it's already noted as a tag). I'll add that to the question text too.

Comment: @lonix my guess is that you expect `**` to do recursive globbing, right? But that needs to be enabled in bash; check the output of `shopt` for `globstar`!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks Marcus, that worked.

Comment: @lonix in that case, converted my comment to an answer, so you can accept that and mark this question as solved.

Comment: @lonix, yes, I wondered why the output of `set -o` mentioned above wouldn't show the other glob-related options, and jumped to expect you'd be running some non-Bash shell by mistake (people do that a lot with scripts). But of course e.g. `globstar` _isn't_ a `set -o` option, but a `shopt` option, sigh. So yeah, my bad, sorry about that.

Comment: @ilkkachu No worries, thanks for your help and for updating the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you expect `**` to do recursive globbing, right? But that's not enabled by default in Bash and needs to be enabled via `shopt -s globstar` (similarly to `dotglob` and `extglob`). You can also check the value with `shopt globstar`.

(Or `shopt |grep glob` to echo the suggestion of `set -o |grep glob` in the comments; note the difference between `shopt` and `set -o` here.)